# What does "prevently" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

What does *prevently* mean in this paragraph? The original article can be found [here](http://wesleyblog.blogspot.com/2005/05/every-day-is-adventure-and-beavers-are.html):

> [...] Only the activity of insects and frogs that danced around the
>   lilly pads disturbed the water. Hardly a minute had passed when a
>   movement caught the corner of my left eye. Imagination told me that a
>   grandaddy beaver was tromping in clear range of my Winchester Super-X
>   CXP3 power-point game load. Reality told me something else. What I had
>   supposed was a large beaver turned out to be the head of a much larger
>   animal. **It was the presence of this laviathon that had prevently me
>   from seeing any beavers upon arrival.** In a flash, the five-foot
>   reptilian sprang from the brush and exploded into the water with great
>   speed and noise.[...]

Comment: Blogs are not generally resources recommended for reliability in Use of English.

Comment: This is too localized.

Comment: This post looks to me like a *googlewash*... He is posting a link to his blog in a public page that is likely to show up in a lot of google searches. That makes it look like his blog is referenced by other important pages and so increases the importance of his blog. If anyone actually follows the link to the blog, you're only giving him traffic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the rest of the article, which is riddled with misspellings, it's simply a typo for *prevented*. There is no English word **prevently*; I've never heard it, it's not in the dictionary, and there are only 671 Google hits (which look like misspellings of *presently*, *preventable*, *preventive*, ...).

Comment: Does such word as prevenly exist in English?

Comment: No. Never heard it, not in the dictionary, and only 671 google hits.

Comment: The hits seem to be misspellings of *presently*, *preventable*, *preventive*, ....